# How to send a chart as an email body using powershell

Tags: email, powershell, graph, charts

i have the following code. this is used to compare two dates for data and then saves it in a 3D chart.

```
     [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization")
$scriptpath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# chart object
 $chart1 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
 $chart1.Width = 1300
 $chart1.Height = 600
 $chart1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White

# title 
 [void]$chart1.Titles.Add("Order Rate")
 $chart1.Titles[0].Font = "Arial,13pt"
 $chart1.Titles[0].Alignment = "topLeft"

# chart area 

$chartarea3D = New-Object  System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea3DStyle
# $chartarea.Name = "ChartArea1"
$chartarea3D.Enable3D = $true
$ChartArea = $chart1.ChartAreas.Add('ChartArea');
$ChartArea.Area3DStyle = $chartarea3D
$chartarea.AxisY.Title = "Orders"
$chartarea.AxisX.Title = "Hour"
$chartarea.AxisY.Interval = 200
$chartarea.AxisX.Interval = 1

# legend 
$legend = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend
$legend.name = "Legend1"
$chart1.Legends.Add($legend)

# data source

#region Invoke sql
function Invoke-Sqlcmd2 
<some code>

 #endregion 
 $datasource = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance yyyyyy -Database     internetordering -Query "SELECT  DATEPART(hh,createdon) AS hour, Count(*)Orders from dbo.OrderHeader (nolock ) 
    where isimported = 1 and createdon between '01/27/2015 0:00:00' and '01/27/2015 23:59:59'
    group by DATEPART(hh,createdon)"

   $datasource2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance zzzzzz -Database internetordering -Query "SELECT  DATEPART(hh,createdon) AS hour, Count(*)Orders from InternetOrdering.dbo.OrderHeader (nolock ) 
    where isimported = 1 and createdon between '01/28/2015 0:00:00' and '01/28/2015 23:59:59'
    group by DATEPART(hh,createdon)"


# data series
[void]$chart1.Series.Add("OrdersLastMonthEOM")
#$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].ChartType = "Column"
$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].ChartType = "Line"
$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].IsVisibleInLegend = $true
$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].BorderWidth  = 3
#$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].chartarea = "ChartArea1"
$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].Legend = "Legend1"
$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].color = "#62B5CC"
$datasource | ForEach-Object  {$chart1.Series["OrdersLastMonthEOM"].Points.addxy( $_.Hour , $_.Orders) }

# data series
[void]$chart1.Series.Add("OrdersThisMonthEOM")
#$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].ChartType = "Column"
$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].ChartType = "Line"
$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].IsVisibleInLegend = $true
$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].BorderWidth  = 3
#$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].chartarea = "ChartArea1"
$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].Legend = "Legend1"
$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].color = "#E3B64C"
$datasource2 | ForEach-Object {$chart1.Series["OrdersThisMonthEOM"].Points.addxy( $_.Hour , $_.Orders) }

# save chart
$chart1.SaveImage("$scriptpath\SplineArea2.png","png")
```

This creates a cool 3D Line graph on ISplineArea.png . I need a way to send this graph in a body of an email. Can anyone help with that.

Answer (score 0):

[From Here](http://www.sharepointfire.com/MyBlog/2011/12/send-email-with-images-in-powershell/)

In short, you have to send a message as HTML, attach pictures, set ContentID (cid) for every picture shown in your HTML and address them in `img` tag like `<img src="cid:content-id-you-assigned" >`

```
$EmailFrom = "NoReply@siteone.ok"
$EmailSubject = "Email including images in HTML"
$smtpServer = "mx1.siteone.ok"
$SendTo = "mailto@sitetwo.ok"

# Working with attachment and HTML code 
$Image = "C:\scripts\MailScript\TestImage.png"
$att1 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image)
$att1.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png"
$att1.ContentId = "MyAttachment"
$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
$mailmessage.Attachments.Add($att1)
$body = "<p style='font-family: Calibri, sans-serif'>
     <img src='cid:MyAttachment' /><br />
     This is a demonstration mail. 
     </p>"

$mailmessage.from = $emailfrom
$mailmessage.To.add($sendto)
$mailmessage.Subject = $emailsubject
$mailmessage.Body = $body
$mailmessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
$SMTPClient.Send($mailmessage)
$att1.dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you Filimonic, appreciate the response. i added the same lines and it is sending the email fine with the attachment as Splinearea2.png. Only thing is, the chart is not showing on the body of the email and just shows as a small broken image icon with a red x. but if i open the attachment, the chart is fine.
any ideas why that might be happening.

Comment: Check your set `$attachement.ContentId` and `<img src="cid:` are same. Also possibly something wrong with quotes. It's better to analyse raw eml file to find a problem

Comment: thank you. was just a problem with the quotes, ''. :) works great now. :)